# mongodb command line twenty result limit is driving me crazy

Tags: mongodb, console, command

Is there a way around 'Type "it" for more'?

`db.collection.find({},{myField:1})`

I just have a few hundred entries and I want to copy/paste out of the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `limit`

`db.collection.find({},{myField:1}).limit(1000)`

Then you can go the next page or increase limit if you need.

My bad. I missed the word mongo console.

You can do it in couple of ways.

1. `toArray()` - instead limit. Without a number.
2. DBQuery.shellBatchSize  - set this value to the number you want.

[Refer this section](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-mongo-shell/index.html#change-the-mongo-shell-batch-size)

Comment: Hm, that doesn't seem to work.

```.limit(4)``` does cap results at 4, but 1000 still caps at 20

Comment: Thanks @Gibbs, verified. What a big relief.